# three.js video textures in ios play back in a separately launched player - ideas?

Tags: ios, video, three.js, textures

I'm trying to get a video texture to play on geometry in iOS using three.js but instead of playing the video as a texture, the browser launches the video in a player that covers the window. I have tried this loading the mp4 directly in the texture, loading it first through a canvas, etc. If I pause the video with the player's controls, and "pinch", the player goes away leaving a paused texture on the geo at the paused frame.

Examples on line such as: 
http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.videotexture/examples/videotexture.html exhibit the same issue. So I'm assuming this is a new "feature" in iOS.

Is this an iOS issue, a Safari issue? If anyone has a workaround I would appreciate it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by setting the 'playsinline' attribute on the video element. There is also a polyfill: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iphone-inline-video

Answer (score 0):

found a link from an iOS post that led to an Apple page. Small screen iOS devices play back video at full screen - apparently overriding whatever instructions there may be in the HTML

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: Someone seems to have gotten around this issue @scott-singer..: http://d8d913s460fub.cloudfront.net/krpanocloud/video/airpano/index.html